# Why Hibernate Criteria projection Return a Null Object?

Tags: hibernate, projection, hibernate-criteria

What i want is to send Mobile number to the database and fetch Customer object. i debug following code and saw null customer object returned. Any help?

```
 public Customer unSuccessfulLoginAttempts(String mobileNumber) {
    log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<| Unsuccessful Logging Attempts  Repository Starting|>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {}" ,mobileNumber );
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class,"c");
    Criterion mobile = Restrictions.eq("c.phone1",mobileNumber);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u.phone1", mobileNumber));
    return (Customer) criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your alias is `"c"` but you are using `"u"`.
You need to have:

```
List customer = session.createCriteria(Customer.class)
                           .add(Restrictions.eq("phone1", mobileNumber))
                           .list();
```

Also your variable mobile remains unused.

Comment: Omg .. this was a problem . please give me some minutes to correct and check

Comment: Mobile variable i added only to check when um in the debug mode

Comment: Sir here return value is a object or a list?

Comment: Still the return value is null

Comment: Any more suggetions pls?

Comment: check your spellings check the incoming telephone string. Is there a trailing space. This example is straight from the books. You are overlooking something IMO.

Comment: Is your property name phone1 ? Post your Customer.class mapping.

Comment: This is the mapping @Column(name = "phone_1")
    private String phone1;

Comment: Are there spaces at the end of the telephone string ? Try trimming.

Comment: This is the request i`m sending {"request":{"msisdn":"+94798796016"}} exact the same value in the database

Comment: All these are ok. problem was i had to annotate my service layers as @Transactional. Thanks for ur effort